# katex, macros when using auto-render

Tags: javascript, macros, katex

I understand how to use macros with `katex.render` for on-the-fly rendering, but I can't figure out how to achieve that when using `renderMathInElement`. The code below doesn't work.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            delimiters: [
              {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
              {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true},
              {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
              {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false}
            ],
            macros: {
              {"\\R": "\\mathbb{R}"}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've opened a [PR on KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/656) to allow any option supported by `katex.render` to be passed to `renderMathInElement`.

Comment: @Alex, do you want to document this as an answer here?